# Errors casting a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, compiler-errors

I have:

```
unsigned char *programBinary = (unsigned char) malloc(binarySize);
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
test.c:127:34: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
test.c:127:33: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

This is fairly new to me so I'm unsure as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `(unsigned char*)` not `(unsigned char)`

Comment: No problem. And thanks @Justin Etherier, forgot the code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a pointer to `unsigned char`. What you probably wanted is `static_cast<unsigned char*>` instead of `(unsigned char)`.

**UPDATE:**

Initially I have immediately thought that this is a C++ question just because you were trying to cast in a first place.

In C, you do not need to cast `void*` to pointers of other types explicitly. So simply write this:

```
unsigned char *programBinary = malloc(binarySize);
```

Comment: But isn't `static_cast` C++ instead of C?

Comment: @JustinEthier: Sorry, I thought this is a C++ question because in C there is no need for a cast at all. I've updated my answer. Thanks for  the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

The malloc function returns a (void *) - that is a pointer (W-pointer as noted in the warning message).

Hence you need to cast the return value to a (unsigned char*)

```
unsigned char *programBinary = (unsigned char*) malloc(binarySize);
```